# Using Vlfeat's C API for quickshift

Tags: c++, opencv, netbeans, computer-vision, vlfeat

I have installed vlfeat on my pc and seem to have got it working on netbeans.

I am currently trying to use vlfeat's quickshift function but I am unable to find any references on how to do the following:

1. Import input images in vlfeat's C/C++ code using quickshift
   segmentation.
2. I need to initialize a quickshift object 'vl_qs_type'
   for this purpose, and I am unable to find a way to do this.

Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I need to use VLFeat's implementation of Quick Shift, as well. The following snippets illustrate how to use the implementation from C++. As I am using OpenCV to read image, first include OpenCV together with the VLFeat header files:

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

extern "C" {
    #include "generic.h"
    #include "quickshift.h"
}
```

After downloading VLFeat (in my case the archive contains the folder `vlfeat-0.9.18`), I use CMake to add `vlfeat-0.9.18/vl` as include directory. Otherwise you have to adjust the above code. Then, the following code reads an image, converts the image to the required format and runs Quick Shift.

**Note:** The following snippet is only an extract of my original code and, thus, is not tested as it is presented below.

```
// Read an image using OpenCV, I assume a color image to be given;
// the image will be loaded in BGR color space.
cv::Mat mat = cv::imread("Lenna.png", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

// Convert image to one-dimensional array.
double* image = new double[mat.rows*mat.cols*mat.channels()];
for (int i = 0; i < mat.rows; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < mat.cols; ++j) {
        image[j + mat.cols*i + mat.cols*mat.rows*0] = mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[0];
        image[j + mat.cols*i + mat.cols*mat.rows*1] = mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[1];
        image[j + mat.cols*i + mat.cols*mat.rows*2] = mat.at<cv::Vec3b>(i, j)[2];
    }
}

// Create a new quickshift instance using the image, the height and width of the
// image as well as the number of channels.
VlQS* quickShift = vl_quickshift_new(image, mat.rows, mat.cols, mat.channels());
vl_quickshift_set_kernel_size(quickShift, 5);

// Run Quick Shift.
vl_quickshift_process(quickShift);
```

However, I could not figure out how to interpret and use the output of the implementation, yet.

Answer (score 0):

1. In the **Usage** part of this website [Quick shift image segmentation](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/quickshift.html#quickshift-intro), a simple pipeline is presented.
2. As explained in the API doc of [vl_quickshift_new](http://www.vlfeat.org/api/quickshift_8h.html#aec706b048c3f4de42a118e242fbd0105):

   - The `image` is an array of `vl_qs_type` values with three dimensions (respectively widht, height, and channels). Typically, a color (e.g, RGB) image has three channels. The linear index of a pixel is computed with: `channels * width* height + row + height * col`.
   - `vl_qs_type` is double, i.e. `typedef double  vl_qs_type`.
   - `image` is just a double array.

I am not sure of your purpose of adopting Vlfeat but I highly recommend using Matlab wrappers of Vlfeat, since there are many tutorials available and many algorithms are simple single matlab function call.